# Are weight and kernel regulalizer same?

Tags: python, keras, convolution

All around the web I read about `weight regularizer` in Keras but I can not find it in specifications. I can see only kernel regularizer there. I assume that it is same since kernels are some kind of weights. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right. See this line here from the Keras Convolutional Layer documentation:

> kernel_regularizer: Regularizer function applied to the kernel weights
>   matrix (see regularizer).

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at https://keras.io/regularizers/ where it is not mentioned.